# Ansible, set fact when yum package is installed

Tags: ansible

I'm a little stumped by this one.  I'm attempting to script a full oracle installation, I've got all the OSB Suite and other parts sorted but the JDK is driving me crazy.
The validate runs but I cannot get it set a fact correctly.  I'm definitely missing something simple.

vars/main:

```
# vars for jdk
java_jdk_already_installed: false
java_jdk_installer: "jdk-8u271-linux-x64.rpm"
java_jdk_definition: 'jdk1.8.x86_64'
```

tasks/validate:

```
- name: "validate java installation {{ java_jdk_installer }}"
  yum:
    list: "{{ java_jdk_definition }}"
    disable_gpg_check: yes
  register: java_yum_output

- debug:
    msg: "java state {{ java_yum_output }}"

- set_fact:
    java_jdk_already_installed: true
  when: java_yum_output|length > 0
```

Debug output with the package present:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "java state {'msg': '', 'results': [{'name': 'jdk1.8', 'arch': 'x86_64', 'epoch': '2000', 'release': 'fcs', 'version': '1.8.0_271', 'repo': '@System', 'nevra': '2000:jdk1.8-1.8.0_271-fcs.x86_64', 'yumstate': 'installed'}], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}"
}
```

Debug with the package missing:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "java state {'msg': '', 'results': [], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}"
}
```

I can get it to skip if I use

```
when: java_yum_output.results[0].yumstate == "installed"
```

But if the package isn't present, the list has no elements and errors.  Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: So just check whether list has no element (aka is empty) beforehand and use the `AND` operator?

Comment: I’ve tried java_yum_output |length > 0 and .results > 0 but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        java_jdk_already_installed: true
      when: java_yum_output.results.0.yumstate|default('') == "installed"
```

Comment: Thankyou Vladmir, you wonderful person.  I'm only 2 weeks into Ansible so that'd have taken me a while to get to :)